# Laravel sql select users email who listed rooms where status = listed

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I have these 2 tables:

```
**users**
id | name | email | ...
-----------

**rooms**
user_id | title | status | ...
---------------------------
```

How can i select all users's email with rooms where rooms status is Listed in Laravel 5 ?

Comment: where is users_email, in table users ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want, not too sure as there is a lack of information. `select users_email_column from tablename where status = 'Listed'`. Where is `users_email` in table, what is `listed rooms` field and we don't know what the `status` looks like in terms of sample data.

Comment: @DanielE. table users = id, name, email...

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do, you have to use "with" and "has"

```
    $user = User::with(['room'])->whereHas('room,function($query){
            $q->where('status',1);

    })->get();
```

create model of User and Room & a relation in user name room.
May be the above one solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have already define a relation between `App\User` and `App\Room` Models like this.

```
class User {
    /* other codes in your model goes here */
    public function rooms(){
        return $this->hasMany(App\Room::class);
    }
}

class Room {
    /* other codes in your model goes here */
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }
}
```

You can retrieve all users's email with rooms where rooms status is Listed like this

```
$users= \App\User::with(['rooms' => function($query){
    $query->where('status', 'listed');
}])->pluck('email');
```